# How to make a map on Leaftlet? Error in addPolygons and object cannot be found

Tags: r, leaflet

I am making a map through leaflet from a tutorial.I followed it and I used the code below to make the map:

```
m<- leaflet() %>%
   setView(-96,37,4) %>%
   addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.Toner)%>%
   addPolygons(data =districts,
               weight = 1,
               smoothFactor = 0.5,
               color = "white",
               fillOpacity = 0.8,
               fillcolor= pal(fb$per.content))
m
```

However, i keep getting this error:

```
Error in addPolygons(., data = districts, weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,  : 
  unused argument (fillcolor = pal(fb$per.content))
> m
Error: object 'm' not found
```

I am not sure why I got an error, I appreciate input here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so if you look at your error code, you have an unused argument `(fillcolor = pal(fb$per.content))`.

This means that the code isn't being carried out, so we know the error lies in this lil code block. From a glance you've forgotten to put ~ before pal(), as In `~pal(fb$per.content)`. I recently made the same mistake and took me ages to figure it out, let me know if this works for you!

Comment: Hey, I ended trying your suggestion and it still does not work. The error I get is         ``` Error in addPolygons(., data = districts, weight = 1, smoothFactor = 0.5,  : 
  unused argument (fillcolor = ~pal(fb$per.content))
``

Comment: This may seem obvious and I apologise if you've just typed it differently in stackoverflow, but have you checked the c in "fillColor" is capitalised?

Comment: No stress, happy I could help